# Friend list through relations

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm creating a social media app. I'm able to allow the current user to search for a `PFUser` and add the user to a `friendship` relation. I'm struggling on accessing the friendship relation and getting all the friends to create a table view right now. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Relation` type in **Parse** represents just like what it literal meaning is. It's just a relation that contains no data. If you want to access the data inside the relation. You will need to perform query on it like so:

```
let query = relation.query() // I assume relation is an instance of PFRelation you want
```

Actually, **Parse** tutorial provides us a very comprehensive guide and you should check that first: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations

Comment: Yeah I tried looking at it a bit and I still got pretty confused. So I would perform a query inside the key that equals "friend" (the relation)

Comment: It's not confused. That's why they called it `Relation`. It's just relation only.

Comment: so are you saying this wouldn't be the best way to accomplish my task?

Comment: that's how you fetch the data. I mean `Relation` is not confused at all. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE: This answer provides alternatives to using Relations to make a Friend System***

I have created a friend system in two ways using Parse and both a function of your specific needs.

The first time I implemented a friend system. I had a table of `Users` and a table of `Relationships`. The `Relationships` table stored the usernames (or ObjectIds) of the two users in a relationship and the state of that relationship (friends, request sent, etc). The problem with this is that the queries can be kinda complicated, and if you have a lot of users, this may end up being too slow.

The second option is storing friend information in the `User` table itself. For each user, you add the columns with they type Array: `Friends`, `RequestSent`, and `RequestReceived`. Anytime a user sends a request they update their own user row and send a message to CloudCode to update the other affected user. Take a look at this example:

User A sends a request to User B:

1. User A adds user B's name to `RequestSent`
2. User A sends a message to cloud code that he/she wants to add user B
3. CloudCode adds User A's name to User B's `RequestReceived`

User B wants to accept User A's request

1. User B adds user A's name to `Friends`
2. User B removes user A's name from `RequestSent`
3. User B sends a message to CloudCode that he/she wants to accept User A's friend Request
4. CloudCode adds user A's name to `Friends`
5. CloudCode removes user A's name from `RequestReceived`

With this option, you never perform any server side queries. You only ever perform `get` operations. The downside to this option is if the logged-in user has thousands of friends/requests, it will take a while to download that information.

Note: The reason you have to use CloudCode is that a User can only change information about him/herself. The other option is to have CloudCode manage all the adding/removing so better checks can be made.

I found with this method that you can sometimes have one user who is listed a a friend in another users row but not their own. Controlling everything from CloudCode could eliminate this kind of error.

Comment: You can use a UserFriends table with the structure |[Friends] | [sentRequests] | [receivedRequests] that can be read and written by everybody to do the process described above. The question remains on how to deal with update conflicts where one user reads to update and before it has updated another user reads the record and when he updates overstrikes the previous update. This problem affects also the CloudCode. Any idea on how to solve this problem in an efficient manner without locks?

Comment: About locks in Parse.. this link kind of solves the problem https://parse.com/questions/locking